# I've got a Qt Assignment that I just can't seem to get working. Here's the assignment description:

Tags: c++

Write a Qt Graphical User Interface (GUI) program to generate a username and an initial
password given the full name of the user.
Given below are the rules for generating a valid username:
• It consists of 5 lower case characters.
• The user name is created by combining the first 4 characters of the first name with the first
character of the surname.
• If the first name does not have 4 characters, more characters are taken from the surname to
make up the user name.
• If the total number of characters in the first name and the surname is less than 5 then append
sufficient number of 0s to create the username.
An initial password is generated by combining randomly selected 5 characters from the full
name of the user.
Note than no spaces are allowed in the username or password.
User input should be obtained using a QInputDialog. You can expect the full name as a
single string where each word is separated using a space. For example: Mike William
Owen. The output (username and password) should be displayed using a QMessageBox.
You need not do any verification of the user input. You can assume that the user will enter at
least two words in the QInputDialog. Assume that the first word of the input is the first name
and the last word in the name is the surname - for example, for the sample input Mike
William Owen, Mike should be read as the first name and Owen as the surname and the
generated username should be mikeo.

Problem I cannot figure out is - • If the total number of characters in the first name and the surname is less than 5 then append
sufficient number of 0s to create the username. Here is my code:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QStringList>

int randInt(int low, int high)
{
   return qrand() % ((high + 1) - low) + low;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QString userFullName = QInputDialog::getText(0, "User Name", "Enter name and surname (First, middle and last name)");
   QStringList userInfo = userFullName.split(" ");
   QString password;
   //QString DisplayName;

   QString firstName = userInfo.first();
   QString lastName = userInfo.last();

   QString DisplayName = userInfo.join(" ");

   QString FullName = firstName.toLower() + lastName.toLower();

   if (FullName.size() < 5)
   {
       FullName.insert(4,"0");
   }

   qsrand(QTime::currentTime().msec());


   int userL = FullName.length();

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
       int num = randInt(0,userL);
       password[i] = FullName[num];
   }

   if(userInfo.size() >= 2)
   {
       QString lastNameChars;
       QString firstNameChars;

       if (lastName.size() >= 4)
       {
           QString firstL = QString(lastName.at(0));
           firstL.toUpper();
           QString secondL = QString(lastName.at(1));
           secondL.toLower();
           QString thirdL = QString(lastName.at(2));
           thirdL.toLower();
           QString fourthL = QString(lastName.at(3));
           fourthL.toLower();
           lastNameChars = firstL + secondL + thirdL + fourthL;
           firstNameChars = QString(firstName.at(0));
       }
       else if (lastName.size() == 3)
       {
           QString firstL = QString(lastName.at(0));
           firstL.toUpper();
           QString secondL = QString(lastName.at(1));
           secondL.toLower();
           QString thirdL = QString(lastName.at(2));
           thirdL.toLower();
           lastNameChars = firstL + secondL + thirdL;
           firstNameChars = QString(firstName.at(0)) +
           QString(firstName.at(1));
       }
       else if (lastName.size() == 2 )
       {
           QString firstL = QString(lastName.at(0));
           firstL.toUpper();
           QString secondL = QString(lastName.at(1));
           secondL.toLower();
           lastNameChars = firstL + secondL;
           firstNameChars = QString(firstName.at(0)) + QString(firstName.at(1)) + QString(firstName.at(2));
       }
       else if (lastName.size() == 1 )
       {
           QString firstL = QString(lastName.at(0));
           firstL.toUpper();
           lastNameChars = firstL;
           firstNameChars = QString(firstName.at(0)) + QString(firstName.at(1)) + QString(firstName.at(2)) + QString(firstName.at(3));
       }

       QString UserName = lastNameChars + firstNameChars.toLower();

       QString response = QString("The user: %3\nUsername: %2\nPassword: %1\n").arg(password).arg(UserName).arg(DisplayName);
       QMessageBox::information(0, "Results", response);
   }
   else
   {
       QMessageBox::information(0, "Error", "Incorrect input data");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [help] and take the [tour]. "please debug my code" is not a question.

Comment: Also read about [mcve]. This: "If the total number of characters in the first name and the surname is less than 5 then append sufficient number of 0s to create the username." sounds like you should present us a small method that takes name and surname as input and returns the username, rather than a wall of code with lots of stuff unrelated to your actual problem

Comment: Just some general suggestions: a) Do not write all your code in the main funcion, rather create one or more fuctions with a meaningful name for the specific task for example QString createUsername(QString name, QString surname) b) Prepare some test cases to verify that your function works for example result = createUserName("john","smith") -> result should be "johns" and then result = createUserName("joe","black") --> result should be joebl .. this way you are likely to get to some solid results much quicker.

Comment: Thanks all, I'm not really a programmer and is part of my Varsity curriculum from my BSC degree and appreciate any help/guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Start by isolating whether `FullName` has more than 5 characters.

- If `FullName` does have more than 5 characters, we check for two outcomes:

  - If `firstName`has more than 5 characters, then `UserName` is just the first 4 letters of `firstName` and the first letter of `lastName`.
  - If less, `UserName` is then all of `firstName` and the number of characters it was short of 5 taken from `lastName`.
- Otherwise, `FullName` doesn't have more than 5 characters and we loop through and append a `0` for the number of characters `FullName` was short of 5, and that becomes the `UserName`.

Here is an example:

```
    ...
    if(userInfo.size() >= 2)
    {
       QString lastNameChars;
       QString firstNameChars;
       QString UserName;

       if (FullName.size() > 5)
       {
            if (firstName.size() > 5)
            {
                UserName = firstName.left(4) + lastName.left(1);
            }
            else
            {
                UserName = firstName.left(firstName.size()) +
                           lastName.left(5 - firstName.size());
            }
       }
       else
       {
           UserName = FullName;
           for (int i = 0; i < 5 - FullName.size(); i++)
           {
               UserName += "0";
           }
       }
    ...
```